# Why is $P(X=x, Y=y, Z=z)$ = $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, multinomial-theorem

So I was reading this question:
[What are the chances that out of $n$ people playing rock, paper, scissors, only two choices are picked?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885933/what-are-the-chances-that-out-of-n-people-playing-rock-paper-scissors-only)

and saw this type of answer in other place as well. The:

> But you can also represent this as a multinomial distribution with
> the PMF of the form:
>
> $P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)=\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}(\frac{1}{3})^n$, where n=x+y+z.

So my question is why.
I want to break it into small "chunks" to understand it better. From where did the fraction of
$\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$ come.

I do think that I understand why I need to make a power of $n$ for $\frac{1}{3}$ , because the probability of getting any of the options (rock, scissors or paper) is $\frac{1}{3}$, and the probability is the same for all of them, so I just need to multiply it by the number of the total players which is $n$, right?

I think I just don't really understand how the joint PMF idea helps me or even works in general (?)
I mean yes. I do know the whole theory about joint PMF, but I can't really understand how it worked here.

And also this whole multinomial theorem idea, is not very clear to me in this question and answer.

Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$ is in fact equal to ${n\choose x}{n-x\choose y}$, i.e. this is exactly the number of ways to split $n$ distinct objects into three groups with $x$, $y$ and $z$ elements respectively. (First choose the $x$ elements in the first group, for each choice choose $y$ out of the remaining $n-x$ elements in the second group.) Does it help?

Comment: I also thought about it. That we choose $x$ from $n$, then we stay with choosing $y$ from what remained which means $n-x$, but what about the $z$? it's just what left a.k.a $n-x-y=z$? Sorry for the noob question but why $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$ equals to ${n\choose x}{n-x\choose y}$ ? So in conclusion - we actually calculate the number of ways to split n objects into 3 groups with $x,y$ and $z$. and then multiply it by the probability of each one of them (which is the same for them all which is $\frac{1}{3}$ with a power of the total number of the players? This is the joint PMF overall idea?

Comment: Yep, that *is* the idea. As for the calculation, you know that ${n\choose x}=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$? Then ${n\choose x}{n-x\choose y}=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}\cdot\frac{(n-x)!}{y!(\underbrace{n-x-y}_z)!}=\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$ (as $n-x-y=z$ because $x+y+z=n$).

Comment: Got it, thank you! And the $(\frac{1}{3})^n$ is because the probability for all of them (x,y and z) is $\frac{1}{3}$ and we multiply it by the number of the total players which is $n$? Why are we doing that?

Comment: The probability that those players have made any particular choice of rock-paper-scissors is $\frac{1}{3^n}$. (There are $3^n$ equally probable choices.) Now the number of those *choices* where there are $x$ rocks, $y$ papers and $z$ scissors is $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$. Thus, the probability to hit one of those choices, and have exactly $x$ rocks, $y$ papers and $z$ scissors is $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}\cdot\frac{1}{3^n}$.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it!